# JQuery toggle function, JS parameter passing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, parameter-passing

I've made a button with toggle action to display data (show/hide on click).

It all works as expected, data is hidden at start because of `display: none` and then whenever I click on it once it appears, and second click hides the data.

**Goal:** I'm trying to make a polymorphic function with argument `name` that I would pass so that every different `id` could use the same function, without repeating the same code over and over again. I'd be very grateful if somebody could steer me in the right direction, I think the answer is pretty easy, just can't see it atm.

**Problem 1.** When I implemented it the way shown below, it requires on the first attempt 3 mouse clicks, and then 2 to perform the action of `show/hide`.

***JS***

```
<script>
function show_panel() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                    $("#add_group").toggle(); // div id
            });
    });
}
</script>
```

***HTML***

```
<button onclick="show_panel()">Add group</button>
<div id="add_group" style="display: none">
```

*Note: Code without being wrapped inside a function works as expected (1click for every action):*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                    $("#add_group").toggle();
            });
    });
</script>

<button">Add group</button>
<div id="add_group" style="display: none">
```

**Problem 2.** Passing the `id` correctly to the function.

According to code from **Problem 1** I've modified the script:

```
Line 2: function show_panel(name) {
Line 5: $("#".concat(name)).toggle(); // name is the div id I want to pass
```

I've so far been trying to pass the `id` without success

```
<button onclick="show_panel('add_group')"> ...
<button onclick="show_panel("add_group")"> ...
<button onclick="show_panel(add_group)"> ...
```

Hope that this is a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more dynamic use the `data` attribute on `button`.

HTML:

```
<button data-id="add_group"> Add Group </button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $('#' + $(this).data('id')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: You have to use only this much code, remove your old code

Comment: What I meant is that this function has no name attached to it.

Comment: @ConsiderMe No need to keep the code inside function. This is similar as calling function `onclick`, except following better practices.

Comment: @ConsiderMe Yes, this is anonymous function and is called for each button click

Answer (score 1):

Give the button an attribute to indicate which `<div>` it should be associated with:

```
<button class="show-stuff" data-target="add_group">Add Group</button>
```

Then your handler can use that attribute to find the element to show:

```
$(function() {
  $(".show-stuff").click(function() {
    var clicked = this, $clicked = $(clicked), target = $clicked.data("target");

    $("#" + target).toggle();
  });
});
```

The `data-target` attribute value is made available by jQuery via the `.data()` API.

Comment: @ConsiderMe I don't know what you mean at all, unfortunately. In what way has this not worked? Are there errors?